# Button Has A Big Clickable Area JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

On touch devices, the button click event gets triggered when I click outside the button, please check the screen recording here: https://www.loom.com/share/745ba9de7d264c9796c152869a1a7b95.

For the code, I'm using a simple button element inside the body, and a simple click event using addEventListener that triggers a console.log.

Here we go, the code:

```
  <body>
    <button id="test" type="button">test</button>

    <script>
      const button = document.querySelector("#test");
      button.addEventListener("click", handleInteraction);

      function handleInteraction(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log("clicked");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Does anyone know why is that happening?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have any CSS? I don't see how plain HTML or JS could be doing this, it might just be that touch devices allow approximate touching because it's hard to be exact with fingers.

Comment: No CSS, just HTML and JavaScript. And No I did some testing, so if you use the touch event, like touchstart event, this behavior will not occur. Of course, I can develop a script that uses both depending on the device, But I would love to know why this is happening, so that I may not need to write all that logic.

Comment: Seems to be a browser thing, checked on firefox and brave no issues.